# How to get javascript var data from html element? (working with canvasjs)

Tags: javascript, html, canvasjs

I am trying to make a chart with CanvasJS. Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 360px; width: 100%;"></div>
<div id="test1">100</div>
<div id="test2">110</div>
```

and my JS is

```
var dataPoint1 = document.getElementById("test1");
var dataPoint2 = document.getElementById("test2");

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
{  
  data: [
  {
    type: "column",
    dataPoints: [
        { label: "Apple", y: dataPoint1},
        { label: "Mango", y: dataPoint2}
    ]
  }
  ]
});

chart.render();
```

See my fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/onlinesquad/6gawzc74/): the chart is not correctly rendered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `innerHTML` in order to access the content in the DOM element. Also, you need to then apply `parseInt` to parse the string in and return an integer.

```
var dataPoint1 = document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML;
var dataPoint2 = document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML;
```

[see your updated jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/62vjxo1a/1/)

In your original code you were setting the variables to the whole element, but not the value in the element. You should always use `console.log` and then you can see in the console the result you are getting. It is also useful to check `typeof` what is in the element, as this would have helped you see that it was returning a `String` as opposed to a `Number`.

i.e `console.log(dataPoint1)` -- Originally this was returning `<div id="test1">10</div>` which would have helped you realise you need to get the value in the div, as opposed to the entire element.

```js
var dataPoint1 = document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML;
var dataPoint2 = document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML;

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
 {  
      data: [
      {
        type: "column",
        dataPoints: [
            { label: "Apple", y: parseInt(dataPoint1)},
            { label: "Mango", y: parseInt(dataPoint2)}
        ]
      }
      ]
    });

 chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/canvasjs/1.7.0/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 360px; width: 100%;"></div>
<div id="test1">10</div>
<div id="test2">12</div>
```

Comment: @GhifariRamadhan glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need value of the element like and convert the values as numbers by prepending a `+` or use `parseInt()`:

```
var dataPoint1 = +document.getElementById("test1").textContent.trim();
var dataPoint2 = +document.getElementById("test2").textContent.trim();
```

or:

```
var dataPoint1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("test1").textContent.trim(), 10);
var dataPoint2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("test2").textContent.trim(), 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the actual content of those elements, probably by using `dataPoint1.innerHTML`. You then need to further parse as an int, with `parseInt()`

See: http://jsfiddle.net/6gawzc74/4/ for my "fix"